# simple-schema ignoring my updates

Tags: javascript, meteor

Trying to create an event that changes a `String` called `status` in my `NetworkApp` collection.

Event:

```
Template.app_detail.events({
  'click .accept': function (e, t) {
    console.log("Accept");
      NetworkApp.update(this._id, {$set:{
        status: "Accepted"
      }});
  },
  'click .reject': function (e, t) {
    console.log("Reject");
    NetworkApp.update(this._id, {$set:{
      status: "Rejected"
    }});
  }
})
```

It updates the last time the application was modified but not the status. No errors appear in the console but it does log `Accepted` or `Rejected` so the code can connect to the db and the helper is being triggered by the buttons. Any help is appreciated!~

---

Simple Schema:

```
NetworkAppSchema = new SimpleSchema({
  ign: {
    type: String,
    label: "IGN"
  },
  discordName: {
    type: String,
    label: "Discord Name"
  },
  memberlength: {
    type: String,
    label: "How long have you been a member at Digital Hazards?"
  },
  languageKnown: {
    type: String,
    label: "What languages do you know?",
    autoform: {
      type: 'textarea'
    }
  },
  whyyou: {
    type: String,
    label: "Why do you want to join the Network staff?",
    autoform: {
      type: 'textarea'
    }
  },
  applicant: {
    type: String,
    label: "Applicant",
    autoValue: function() {
      return Meteor.userId();
    },
    autoform: {
      type: "hidden"
    }
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    label: "Applied At",
    autoValue: function() {
      return new Date();
    },
    autoform: {
      type: "hidden"
    }
  },
  status: {
    type: String,
    label: "Status",
    autoValue: function() {
      return "Pending";
    },
    autoform: {
      type: "hidden",
    }
  }


});
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that `this._id` points to an actual doc?

Comment: Well the `createdAt` field updates every time I trigger the event so it is affecting the collection

Comment: So you're using simple-schema then? Can you share your schema code?

Comment: Added it to OP @MichelFloyd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`autoValue` does not mean `initial value`: your `autoValue` functions are running every time.

For `createdAt` for example you should have:

```
createdAt: {
  type: Date,
  denyUpdate: true,
  autoValue() {
    if (this.isInsert) return new Date();
  },
},
```

this will avoid the `createdAt` ever changing after insert.

Similarly for status:

```
status: {
  type: String,
  label: "Status",
  autoValue() {
    if (this.isInsert) return "Pending";
  },
  autoform: {
    type: "hidden",
  }
}
```

Comment: why is this `this.insert` for one and `this.isInsert` for the other?

Comment: Sorry typo, now fixed.

Comment: Do I need to import anything? I do it and then the update works but the original insert does not. Fixes the bug but creates another.

Comment: Oh sorry, do you have [collection2](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2) installed? That handles the `denyUpdate`